# Sorting items after they have been rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have nested JSON that I am then using to turn into a nested file tree using this module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nested-file-tree

The issue I'm running into is that the order of my JSON is not guaranteed after it is passed through the component and rendered.

The author also supports creating custom folder templates.

```
 function CustomFolder ({ name, currentPath, folderObj, onclick }) {
      return (
        <div className="sort">
          <a ref={(name) => {this.folderName = name}} onClick={onclick}>
            <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open'>&nbsp;</span>
            {name}
          </a>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Is it possible for me to modify how the folders are created so I can then go back and sort the folders, **after they have already been passed through the component.**

For example, go through all the `<span>` tags inside a specific `div` container and alphabetically sort what's inside.

Adding example for more clarity.

Lets say I have this structure already rendered:

```
<div>
    <span className='icon sort'>Folder 3</span>
    <span className='icon sort'>Folder 1</span>
    <span className='icon sort'>Folder 2</span>
</div>
```

How can I re-render to achieve this:

```
<div>
    <span className='icon sort'>Folder 1</span>
    <span className='icon sort'>Folder 2</span>
    <span className='icon sort'>Folder 3</span>
</div>
```

Edit: If anyone has additional recommendations of nested folder modules that may support post rendering please drop a link for me. I've looked extensively and haven't found anything useful.

JSON:

```
const directory = {
  "_contents": [
    {
      "name": "filename_1",
      "path": "filename_1"
    },
    {
      "name": "filename_2",
      "path": "filename_2"
    }
  ],
  "folder_1": {
    "_contents": [
      {
        "name": "filename_1",
        "path": "folder_1/filename_1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "folder_2": {
    "_contents": [],
    "folder_2_1": {
      "_contents": [
        {
          "name": "filename1.md",
          "path": "folder_2/folder_2_1/filename1.md"
        }
      ],
      "folder_2_1_1": {
        "_contents": [
          {
            "name": "filename1.md",
            "path": "folder_2/folder_2_1/folder_2_1_1/filename1.md"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you sort the json data before it is passed to component?

Comment: @Morpheus It is currently sorted before passed in. But since the object is dynamic and deep, the order after mapping is not guaranteed.

Comment: Maybe using `refs` would be a solution -> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Morpheus that looks like it could be useful. So each folder element would receive a `ref` itself?

Comment: If your object is dynamic and deep, there's a module designed to help you called Normalizr. Check it out, might be what you want. https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking. You would have an access to them in `this.refs` and be able to sort.

Comment: @Morpheus I updated my example to include refs, would it look something like that?

Comment: @KyleRichardson can you explain why Normalizr is useful?

Comment: It flattens nested objects and normalizes responses so that you get the same response format all the time.

Comment: @KyleRichardson It looks like it would require me to reformat my JSON, is that correct? I'll update my question with the format my JSON must be in to work with this module. Could you also explain how I would go about using it? I normalize the object, then pass that into the module?

Comment: No you don't reformat your JSON. You create schemas call `normalize(originalData, schema)` and your responses will be flattened and always adhere to the schema you want. Here is the quickstart: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr#quick-start

Comment: @KyleRichardson So what do I do with the normalized response? Pass it into the module, correct? But the module is whats changing the order in the first place, so does normalizing prevent this from happening after its passed in?

Comment: pass your JSON into the module to modify it into the file tree and then pass that object to` normalize()` with a schema that you make.

Comment: @KyleRichardson The JSON itself is already formatted to the file tree. The module just generates a UI from it. I'm not sure this would work, there is no object returned after the module takes the JSON. I can add more code if needed...